# How to decode javascript code within <Script LANGUAGE="JScript.Encode">

Tags: python, javascript

I would like to implement a Python script which has the same functionality as http://www.greymagic.com/security/tools/decoder/
Is the encoding rule open for this type of javascript code encoding?
Thanks.
An example of this：

```
<Script LANGUAGE="JScript.Encode">#@~^TBQAAA==-mD~kk9P'8*R0%p\CD,wr[&fP{~xhPz..lH`EFTc+{W*v~Eq!W {*+B~vqZc+GW{E~v8!W GW%ESB8!* Fc1vBBFZ* F*!ESvFZcyGXFvSEFTcy{*yBSv8!c+{l&v~EqZc+F*WB~EFZ* F*XBBBqTW GlBBBFZ*+GlGE~vFT*yGX%ESB8!*+F*,vSEFTcy{+!vBB8!cyG+qBBBq!W {yB~Eq!W G+fv~EFZc+G*E~vFZ* FvXvBBFT*yGvESEFTW FvGE~Eq!W {vRBSv8!cy{vOB~EqTcyGF!v~vqZc+GFqBBBqTW G{+E~vFZ*yG{2BBBFZcy{GWBSB8!*+FG*ESB8!cy{{vE~EFTc+{FGv~Eq!W {{RB~vqZc+GF1E~v8!W GR!ESB8!* F%qvBBFZ* F% ESvFZcyG0&vSEFTcy{%WBSv8!c+{R*v~EqZc+F%+B~EFZ* F%{BBBqTW GR0BBBFZ*+GR,E~vFT*yG1!ESB8!*+F,FvSEFTcy{O vBB8!cyGOfBBBq!W {1WB~Eq!W GOXv~EFZc+G1E~vFZ* F,{vBBFT*yG1%ESEFTW F,,E~Eq!W 0!ZBSv8!cy0!8B~EqTcy%Z v~vqZc+%ZfBBBqTW %T*E~vFZ*y%TlBBBFZcy0!+BSB8!*+R!GESB8!cy0T%E~EFTc+0Z,v~Eq!W 0qZB~vqZc+%8qE~v8!W %8 ESB8!* RFfvBBFZ* RFcESvFZcy%q*vSEFTcy0F+BSv8!c+08Gv~EqZc+RFRB~EFZ* RF1BBBqTW %yTBBBFZ*+%yFE~vFT*y%+ ESB8!*+R &vSEFTcy0ycvBB8!cy%yXBBBq!W 0++B~Eq!W %y{v~EFZc+%+0E~vFZ* R 1vBBFT*y%f!ESEFTW R&FE~Eq!W 0&yBSv8!cy0&2B~EqTcy%2cv~vqZc+%2XBBBqTW %fE~vFZ*y%fFB*i\mD,2k1b.DmX~x,x+S~bMDlHcvtDYa)&z2r1Rhl  4Em* ^K:zo&6;^yM%J&0J!ZFRNwTv~EtOYa)&&akmchl    tEmX mK:Js&05^.D%z20zZ!+ NwovSEtOYalJz2bmc:l    t!C*cmG:Js&W$myM%z2%zZTfRNwTBSB4ODwlzJ2k1RhC    tECXcmG:JoJ051yMLz2%JT!WR%wTBSv4YYalzJwk1 hl    t!lXR^Gszoz65m.D%&2%zTTlR%wTvBB4DYa)zJwb^RslUt!lX 1W:Joz6;m..%z2%J!Tv %aov~E4YDwl&Jwk^ slUt!ClR^K:Jsz6;1"DNzf%J!T{cLwTv~EtYD2lzJwbm :CU4EC*c^Wszo&6;m".Nzf%JTZ% NwTB~EtDOw=z&wbm hmxt!C*cmWs&oz6;1y.L&fRzT!O LaovSEtYO2=z&wb^c:C    t!l*cmKhzwzW;1y.%J&%JTFZRLaLv~EtDY2)&&ak^RsCx4ECXcmWh&wzW;1"ML&2%J!F8RN2oE~vtDY2lJzwb^Rslx4;C*cmK:&s&W$m"DN&&RzTqyRL2LE~vtDOa)&JwbmRsl  4Em* mK:&oJ0;1"DNz&R&TF2RNwLBSv4YOw=&zak^ slx4;m* mKhJs&6;1yDNz20zZF*RNwLvBBtDOw=zzar^Rsl   t;lX 1Whzw&0$m".Nz&0&ZFXRN2TBSEtDYw=zJ2k1Rhl    t;ClRmKhzwz0$^"DNz2%&!qcL2oESB4YO2=zz2r1Rhl 4!lXcmK:zwz65m.D%z2%&T8GRN2oE~B4OOw=zJwrm hmx4EmXR1Wh&wz05^.D%z20J!qRRNwoE~E4YDwlzJwr^c:l   4Em*R1Ghzwz6;^y.%J&0zZq,cL2LE~B4ODwlzJ2bm sl    tEm*c^Wszoz6;^"MLz20zZ !c%2oE~EtOY2lJz2k1 :mx4;m*R^Gszoz651y.Nz2%zZ 8 Laov~EtOOa)zJ2k1R:mU4Em*cmG:&oJ05m..LJ&0&Z   %aov~E4DY2=zJwk1RsCx4EC*cmGhJsz65m.DLJf0zZ 2R%wLvBB4YD2)Jz2r1R:CU4EC*c^K:&wz6;m.DN&&RzT WR%2TB~E4YDw)J&2k1RslUt;ClR^Ws&sJ05^.DL&fRzT l NwLE~EtYDw=&zak^RslU4!l*c^WszsJW5m.DNzf%&Tyv LaLBBB4ODw)&&ak^RsC  t;m*cmWszw&0$m"DNzf0J! F LaoBBv4YDw=z&wr^c:Cx4;llR^Gszs&W$m"DN&2%&Z RRLaoESB4YOw=z&2bmRsCx4Ell ^WszwzW;^"ML&&R&!y, %aoBSv4YOw=&Jwr1Rslx4EmXR1WhzwzW51yDN&&Rz!2T LaoE~vtOOa)&zarmc:CU4ElX 1Whzw&6;^.DNz&RzZfFcL2oE~v4DYw=&zakmchCx4Em* mGhJs&0$^yML&fRz!f+cL2oESEtODw=zzak1 :mx4Em* ^K:zw&0$myM%&&RzZ&fR%2TBSB4OYa)&&akm hmx4EmXcmGszwz0$m..LJ&0zZ&* NwoESB4YYal&zak1RhlU4!lXR1G:Js&W$my.%J&0zZflR%aoE~B4YD2)Jz2k1RhC    tEmXR1W:Jo&0$m.D%zf0J!fvc%wTBSv4YY2lJz2k1 slU4Em*R1Ws&sJ05m.D%&2%zZfGcLwTvSB4YDwlz&2bm :mUt!lX 1W:&oJ05m..NzfRzZ&%cLaLBBB4YDwl&Jwk1 :mxt!CXR1WszozW51y.LJf%J!f1cLwLvBB4YD2=z&ak1R:mx4;llR^Wszo&6;m..LJ&%JT*!cLaov~v4DY2)J&wbm hmxt;ClR^Ws&wzW$m.DLJ&R&!WF LaovSEtYD2)Jzwb^ :mx4EC* ^K:&sJW;1y.%J&%&TW  LaLE~v4YDw)Jzarmc:Cx4ECXcmWs&sJ0;1".LJ&RzTcf NwLBBvtDY2lJzwr^c:Cx4;m* 1WszsJ0$^yML&&RzT*WRLaLBBBtDO2)Jzak^RhC    t;ll mK:&oJ0;^"ML&&R&ZcXcLaoBBB4OYa)&zak^ slx4;llRmKh&sJ0$m"D%&2%&!WRNwLvBBtOOa)&zar1Rhmx4EllR1G:Js&0$m".Nz&R&!WGRN2LBBB4YOwl&Jwrmchl   t;ClRmGhJs&0$^.D%J&Rz!W%c%wTBSB4YO2=zzarmc:l    4;llR1Whzo&6;^yM%z2%&TW,R%2TBSB4ODwlJzakmc:mUt!lXR1Wh&wz0$^yMLz20&!l!cL2ovSEtOYalzJwr^c:lU4!lXR1GszoJ0$myMLJf%J!XFcL2LE~B4OYa)zJ2rmc:mx4ECXcmG:Joz6;^"MLzf0J!X c%aovBB4YYa)J&wbm :mx4;m*R1G:Jsz65^yMLJ&0zTX2R%wTv~EtOOa)z&2bm :mU4EClR1W:JsJW;1y.LJ&0&Z*cc%wTB~E4OYa)Jz2k^ slUt!C*cmGhJszW51y.LJfRzTl*cLwTBBvtDY2)Jz2r1R:mUt!l*c^G:JsJ05m".Nzf%JT*+R%2TB~v4DY2)J&ak^c:mxt!ll mK:&sJ05^.DLJf%J!*F %wTBBB4YO2=z&wb^RslU4!l* ^K:&sJW$m"MLJ&%J!l0RNwLBBB4ODw)J&wbmRsCUt!llR^Wh&wzW;1"DNzf0J!*1 NwLBBv4YOa)Jzwbmchl  t;llR^GszsJW;1yDN&f%J!+! L2LE~vtDOw=z&2bmRhC    t;ll 1WhJsJ0;1yM%z2%&!+F %aoBBvtDYw=&&wbmc:Cx4;m* mKhzwzW51yD%&2%&!++cL2TBBBtDYalzJwrmc:CU4Ell mK:zw&W;1yML&&0&ZvfRN2oE~v4DYwl&Jwrmchmx4!llRmK:Joz6;^yML&fRz!+*RNwoESvtDYa)&z2r1Rhl 4Em* ^K:zo&6;^yM%J&0J!+*RNwTv~EtOYa)&&akmchl    tEmX mK:Js&05^.D%z20zZv NwovSEtOYalJz2bmc:l t!C*cmG:Js&W$myM%z2%zZ{RNwTBSB4ODwlzJ2k1RhC tECXcmG:JoJ051yMLz2%JTvRR%wTBSv4YYalzJwk1 hl    t!lXR^Gszoz65m.D%&2%zTOR%wTvBB4DYa)zJwb^RslUt!lX 1W:Joz6;m..%z2%J!{! %aov~E4YDwl&Jwk^ slUt!ClR^K:Jsz6;1"DNzf%J!{qcLwTv~EtYD2lzJwbm :CU4EC*c^Wszo&6;m".Nzf%JTF  NwTB~EtDOw=z&wbm hmxt!C*cmWs&oz6;1y.L&fRzTG2 LaovSEtYO2=z&wb^c:C t!l*cmKhzwzW;1y.%J&%JTGWRLaLv~EtDY2)&&ak^RsCx4ECXcmWh&wzW;1"ML&2%J!GlRN2oE~vtDY2lJzwb^Rslx4;C*cmK:&s&W$m"DN&&RzT{+RL2LE~vtDOa)&JwbmRsl  4Em* mK:&oJ0;1"DNz&R&TGFRNwLBSv4YOw=&zak^ slx4;m* mKhJs&6;1yDNz20zZG0RNwLvBBtDOw=zzar^Rsl   t;lX 1Whzw&0$m".Nz&0&ZG1RN2TBSEtDYw=zJ2k1Rhl    t;ClRmKhzwz0$^"DNz2%&!0TcL2oESB4YO2=zz2r1Rhl    4!lXcmK:zwz65m.D%z2%&TRFRN2oE~B4OOw=zJwrm hmx4EmXR1Wh&wz05^.D%z20J!0yRNwoE~E4YDwlzJwr^c:l4Em*R1Ghzwz6;^y.%J&0zZ0&cL2LE~B4ODwlzJ2bm sl   tEm*c^Wszoz6;^"MLz20zZ%cc%2oE~EtOY2lJz2k1 :mx4;m*R^Gszoz651y.Nz2%zZ%l Laov~EtOOa)zJ2k1R:mU4Em*cmG:&oJ05m..LJ&0&Z%v %aov~E4DY2=zJwk1RsCx4EC*cmGhJsz65m.DLJf0zZ%FR%wLvBB4YD2)Jz2r1R:CU4EC*c^K:&wz6;m.DN&&RzT%RR%2TB~E4YDw)J&2k1RslUt;ClR^Ws&sJ05^.DL&fRzT%O NwLE~EtYDw=&zak^RslU4!l*c^WszsJW5m.DNzf%&TO! LaLBBB4ODw)&&ak^RsC  t;m*cmWszw&0$m"DNzf0J!,8 LaoBBv4YDw=z&wr^c:Cx4;llR^Gszs&W$m"DN&2%&Z,yRLaoESB4YOw=z&2bmRsCx4Ell ^WszwzW;^"ML&&R&!O& %aoBbI7l.Par11;sP{P,2i,YwAGAA==^#~@</Script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not open, its just broken. Google "windows script decoder" for [examples](http://www.virtualconspiracy.com/download/scrdec18.c).